# jquery increase number if next prev is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to increase number if next - prev button is clicked. I have four elements, and if I pass on the second element, number should change from 1 to 2, and so on.

[image]

My html code is:

```
        <div class="tl-mask">


        <div class="tl-container">

            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>
            <div class="tl-event"></div>


        </div> <!-- end .tl-container -->

    </div> <!-- end -tl-mask -->
     <button id="prev">prev</button>
     <div class="numbers"></div>
     <button id="next">next</button>
```

Also, even when I click on Element 2, the number should change to 2

Comment: can you show your jquery code

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far and where are you stuck.

Comment: Doesn't accept my code, says that isn't formatted

Comment: Then format it... *facepalm*

Comment: Yes I tried to format, but yet doesn't accept

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alweb2018/29xov7s8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as i've got you question.You want to achive pagination using next & prev. if that so below code  will help you.

```js
$(function() {
  var current = $(".numbers").text();
  $(".prev").on("click", function() {
    current = current - 1;
    $(".numbers").text(current);
  });

  $(".next").on("click", function() {
    current = parseInt(current) + parseInt(1);
    $(".numbers").text(current);
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elements">
  <div>Element 1</div>
  <div>Element 2</div>
  <div>Element 3</div>
  <div>Element 4</div>
</div>

<div class="arrows">
  <div class="prev">Prev</div>
  <div class="numbers">1</div>
  <div class="next">Next</div>
</div>
```

But your this line `I have four elements, and if I pass on the second element, number should change from 1 to 2, and so on` make me think for a second. you also want to change the number if you click on any of the element. if so see below code

```js
$(function() {
  var current = $(".numbers").text();
  $(".element").on("click",function(){
$(".numbers").text($(this).attr("id"));
current = $(this).attr("id");
})
  $(".prev").on("click", function() {
    current = current - 1;
    $(".numbers").text(current);
  });

  $(".next").on("click", function() {
    current = parseInt(current) + parseInt(1);
    $(".numbers").text(current);
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elements">
  <div id="1" class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div id="2" class="element">Element 2</div>
  <div id="3" class="element">Element 3</div>
  <div id="4" class="element">Element 4</div>
</div>

<div class="arrows">
  <div class="prev">Prev</div>
  <div class="numbers">1</div>
  <div class="next">Next</div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I change some codes in your html to achive what you want.
Hope this may help you.. there might be better solution but this is what i came up with.

Comment: Great, thanks. How can I fit in this jQuery code that I'm using with this next prev for something else (to move elements), https://jsfiddle.net/alweb2018/29xov7s8/1/